# Is await must be called when invoke an async method?

Tags: c#, async-await

When we call async method, as long as we don't await the result, we can do something else before we await the result. Something like:

```
var resultTask = GetResultAsync();
//Do something else
var result = await resultTask;
```

I wonder if I skip to await the result, will that cause any side effect?

```
var resultTask = GetResultAsync();
if(GetSomeOtherBooleanValueMethod()){
    var result = await resultTask;
}else{
    //Some other logic here.
    //await resultTask will never happen in this block.
    return;
}
```

Comment: Test it, did you see any side effects?

Comment: How to test side effects? It runs.

Comment: What do you mean by "side effects?" I wouldn't say this as a rule, but I doubt that it's beneficial to start a task before determining whether you're going to need its result. Don't think of the benefit of `async` as making this method faster somehow. Think of it as if you do need to get some result and it's going to take a while, the thread won't be tied up waiting. But overall the application will benefit from not performing tasks it doesn't need.

Comment: Omitting the `await` will fire the method on another thread in the background. If you need to wait for a response use `await`. Otherwise you don't "need" to use the await call. You can assign your method call to some "delegate" like you are doing and perform other tasks while the other thread executes before using await.

Comment: @KSigWyatt Um, no it will not create a new thread? `Task.Run` queues to the thread pool; `await` just says, "resume here when the task is completed."

Comment: @ScottHannen, make sense. I literally tried to squeeze every computational power out of the code, but start unnecessary task is a waste of resource.

Comment: @KennethK. I do it all the time. Calling an `async` method without waiting for a response will still execute the method. You're just instructing the main thread to continue and not hold execution for the completion of the child thread.

Comment: @KSigWyatt That doesn't mean it starts a new thread.

Comment: @KSigWyatt, you don't think it is a waste of your resource?

Comment: @KSigWyatt it doesn't start a new thread. It just means that the thread that initiated the async process resumes with the next statement without waiting for the task to complete. That's the same thing that would happen if you *did* start a new thread, so it looks similar.

Comment: Your question is fundamentally the same as asking, "If a tree falls in a forest and no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?"  Whether anyone happens to observe when a task finishes doesn't change what that task does.  It only changes what whomever's observing it chooses to do in response to what they're observing.

Comment: @KennethK. This example following step 4 here is the effect to which I'm referring. When executing this it may not technically start a new thread. I'm not certian of the implementation of this namespace. But it creates a new `System.Thread.Task` object to run asynchronously. So it may just appear to be the same thing. Similar to what Scott alluded to. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/how-to-make-multiple-web-requests-in-parallel-by-using-async-and-await

Comment: @KSigWyatt And in that example, it's not doing the work in another thread.  it's doing the work asynchronously *without using any additional threads*.  Additionally, whether or not a given operation does or does not use additional threads to achieve its asynchronous has nothing to do with whether or not it's awaited.  Either the implementation of that asynchronous method uses additional threads, whether it's awaited or not, because that's how it was written, or it doesn't, and won't regardless of whether it's awaited or not.

Comment: This is a great article: [There is no thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html). An oddity of async/await is that it's possible to use it in many "happy path" scenarios and never have any idea at all what it actually does. I realized at one point that if you asked me to describe the actual behavior in a sentence that I either couldn't or it would be completely wrong. A key point is that during an async operation, like when a query is executing, there is no thread tied to that process, because if there was there would be nothing for it to do but wait.

Answer (score 1):

> will that cause any side effect?

The effect it causes is that your application can never know when `GetResultAsync` completes.

In particular:

- Your code will not know if `GetResultAsync` fails.
- Your code may consider itself "done" when `GetResultAsync` is still running. If your application exits, `GetResultAsync` will be aborted. Again, without any notification.

The second point is particularly problematic on server frameworks like ASP.NET, which may unload your process if it is "done", thus terminating `GetResultAsync` if it's running.

Answer (score 0):

The only side effect is that it will not wait for the call of `GetResultsAsync()` at any point. Even if you want to use `result` both in the if statement and afterward, you can await the same task multiple times.

```
var resultTask = GetResultAsync();

ResultType result;
if(GetSomeOtherBooleanValueMethod()){
   result = await resultTask;
}else{
    //Some other logic here.
    //await resultTask will never happen in this block.
}
result = await resultTask;
```

Comment: I mean never call await if GetSomeOtherBooleanValueMethod() returns false.

Comment: "it will not wait" Well it won't wait even if you did `await` it, because `await` doesn't just wait.  It performs an action after that asynchronous operation has finished, which is notably different.

Answer (score 0):

This totally depends on what `GetResultAsync();` does. I'm guessing based on its name that all it does is retrieve a value from a web service or database or something. That being said, assuming that

- `GetResultAsync()` actually doesn't have any side effects
- You don't care about the result in the `else` case
- The `GetResultAsync()` method isn't hogging some kind of shared or scarce resource or something
- There is no other scenario in which `GetResultAsync()` could cause a race condition if something else depends on it completing before it runs. For example, if terminating the process early (e.g. through a console application exiting or something) could cause `GetResultAsync()` to leave something in a corrupt state, that would be a problem.

then there's no problem.

The third point is worth commenting on, because if that's the case it could cause a race condition. Broadly speaking, a "shared resource" could be anything from a file handle to an API rate limit.

The broader point is that, if you do something like this, you have to think through any scenario that could possibly cause a race condition.

Answer (score -2):

I think a conclusion can be made as follows:
There is no obvious side effect here as the code can build, no error will happen. We can definitely call async method but never await to get the result. However, it is a wasting of resource, the only benefit is it might save some processing time for who creates the request. But this should be avoided as it is not a best practice.

If you agree, please up vote this answer, I'll decide to mark this as the answer based on up vote count.

Comment: Why would you think not performing any action when a given task completes "wastes resources"?  That could certainly be true in certain situations, where the operation in question has no side effects, only results to be useful to someone, but if an operation results in side effects, running it can have a purpose *even if nothing observes when it finishes*.

Comment: @Servy, IMO, if you run an async method without await result on purpose, you should look for other technique. Async method is not built for "fire and forget". Hangfire is more fit for this type of purpose.

Comment: Fire and forget async is used in WinForms (and I believe WPF) event handlers, so yes it is built for fire-and-forget, but (like any tool) it should be used where appropriate.

Comment: @KennethK. in your opinion. if not considering side effect, do you think it is appropriate practice to execute an async method but never await result?

Comment: @StevenZack Async methods are *absolutely* built to support fire and forget operations.  There are certain pitfalls you can run into, so you need to be mindful of how you handle them (mostly as it pertains to error handling) but it's not only possible, but designed into the system that it will happen.  You personally not liking the practice doesn't mean it wasn't designed into the feature, or that it somehow "wastes resources", which it does not.